# How do I use the alt attribute tag

Tags: html, image, alt

I've made this code:

```
<img src="files/frames/1.png" alt="alt" width="100" height="100"></img>
```

When I remove the main picture, the alternate picture doesn't show up. It just says "alt" (name of whatever I name the picture) and a sort of error img icon.

Comment: What code did you make? Please add some details... I.e. some code... In addition: notice that the alt tag is meant for a description of the image. For instance: `<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face">` . Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp

Comment: I suggest you simply read the documentation. It will answer your question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: alt is for telling what is on the picture it is for google or even for blind people to explaine what is on the picture

Comment: A visually impaired reader using a screen reader such as Orca will hear the alt text in place of the image. A text browser such as Lynx will display the alt text instead of the image. A graphical browser typically will display only the image, and will display the alt text only if the user asks it to show the image's properties or has configured the browser not to display images, or if the browser was unable to retrieve or to decode the image.

Answer (score 1):

The `alt=` tag is not for specifying an alternate image. It is used by screenreaders (blind people use them) to read aloud the web page. Also, if the browser is configured to not download images, the text written in the `alt=""` attribute is displayed on the page instead of the image.

The error image icon is displayed because the image specified in the `src=""` attribute cannot be found.

```
<img src="horse.jpg" alt="Photo of a horse" />
```

If you tell us more about what you want to do, perhaps we can assist further.